# Closed operator and Hille Yosida

Tags: functional-analysis

I am trying to understand the proof of the Hille-Yosida theorem.
I can't understand why the operator is asked to be closed. [theorem of hille yosida](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4I1hn.png).
In [closed opertor properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEmLV.png) we have A closed implies $R(\lambda,A)$ closed and thus bounded by the open graph theorem.
I understand that we need the resolvant operator to be bounded but in our assumption isn't that already the case ? By hypotesis $\lvert R(\lambda,A) \rvert \leq \frac{1}{\lambda}$ for every $\lambda \geq 0$, therefore is bounded.
In my proof, I approximate my operator $A$ with bounded operator $A_n$. The limit $e^{tA_n}$ generate a Semigroup S of generator B, and applying the first part of the theorem we have $\{\lambda \in \mathbb{R} : \lambda >0 \}\subseteq\rho(B)$. We prove that $D(A)=D(B)$ and $B_{|D(A)}=A$. Hence, it is easy to see that there exist $\lambda >0$ such that $R(\lambda,A)=R(\lambda,B)$ and thus $D(A)=D(B)$, which conclude the proof.
Where do I have missed something ?

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the resolvant set is : $\lambda \in \rho(A)$ when $\lambda - A$ has a bounded inverse. When $A$ is closed as you mentioned you can relax this to $\lambda -A$ has an inverse.

In the Hille Yosida theorem you need to require $A$ closed because a generator is automatically closed.

In fact you can show that an operator that is not closed has empty resolvant set, therefore if you assume $(0,\infty) \subset \rho(A)$ then you are assuming $A$ closed.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. My question was"Why is it useful to ask $A$ to be closed since $A$ generator implies A closed and $(0,\infty) \subset \rho(A) $ implies A closed

Comment: @G__C it seems like you never wrote this question. If this is really your question please edit your post. If it really is the only thing you don’t understand then please edit your post to include what you call « Hille Yosida theorem »